# What pentagonal tiling is this?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, polygons, tiling

I'm a little baffled by the following pentagonal tiling:

[image]

It clearly has an 8-tile primitive unit, and thus should be one of types 7-8 (Richard Kershner) or else one of types 9, 11, 12 or 13 (Marjorie Rice) in

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling

However, the angles (as appearing in the photograph, or as in the diagrams below) do not seem to match any of these types (though perhaps, indeed probably, I'm making a mistake). What gives? What is the type of this tiling?

[image]

[image]

(Also, what are the angles, exactly? And are all five side of exactly the same length?)

Comment: Have you seen this recent article : https://www.quantamagazine.org/pentagon-tiling-proof-solves-century-old-math-problem-20170711/ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes :)

Answer (score 5):

I think it's one form of Type 8. It may be a deformation of the equilateral form of the [Cairo pentagonal tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cairo_pentagonal_tiling), but Type 8 seems to fit.

Go to the [Wolfram demo on pentagonal tilings](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PentagonTilings/) and select Type 8. There appear to be three parameters in type 8, but the demo allows you to vary only one parameter. The default setting yields a tiling that corresponds closely to the image you've posted:

[image]

Alternatively, in the Wikipedia page on pentagonal tilings, you can stare at the gif in [the table that defines Type 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling#Kershner_(1968)_Types_6,_7,_8), and eventually it cycles to a form similar to the one in your image.

---

ADDED: The pentagons that form Type 8 tilings have four equal sides and the angles satisfy two constraints. Adopting the labeling found in the article [Tiling the Plane with Congruent Pentagons](https://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/tiling-the-plane-with-congruent-pentagons) by Doris Schattschneider, the pentagons are characterized by
$$ 2A+B=2\pi, \quad 2D+C=2\pi, \quad a=b=c=d.\tag1 $$
Once you've specified a value for $B$ (say), the remaining angles are determined by the above constraints, so there's really only one degree of freedom for a given value of $a$, which explains why there is only one active control in the Wolfram demo for Type 8.

There is a unique Type 8 tiling where all sides are equal. For this equilateral pentagon the Schattschneider article derives the angles (see Table III, Type 8):
$$E=\arccos \frac {\sqrt{13}-3}4, \quad B=C=\pi-E, \quad A=D=\frac\pi2 +\frac E2,$$ or
$$A=D\approx 130^\circ39',\quad B=C\approx 98^\circ 42', \quad E\approx 81^\circ 18'.$$
In the Wolfram demo on pentagonal tilings, set the parameter AA, which corresponds to angle $B$, to $1.72$ (radians). This yields the equilateral Type 8 tiling. The fact that $B+E=C+E=\pi$ means that hexagons will be seen in the result. In your tiling the hexagons are not quite there, so your tiling is described by a slightly different value for AA. (The parameter AA apparently corresponds to the angle formed by the horizontal segment seen at the very center of the demo; it's slightly less than $90^\circ$ in the above screenshot.)

---

ADDED 2: Given a desired value for angle $B$ or non-equal side $e$, you can solve the rest of the Type 8 pentagon by combining constraints (1) with the [law of cosines for pentagons](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2688227):
$$
a^2+b^2+c^2 - 2ab\cos A - 2bc \cos B + 2ac \cos(A+B)=d^2+e^2-2de\cos D.$$
As an example, [this Wolfram Alpha query](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=3-2+cos%28A%29+-2+cos%28B%29+%2B+2+cos%28A%2BB%29%3D1%2Bx%5E2-2x+cos%28D%29%2C+2%2Bx%5E2+-2+cos%28C%29+-2x+cos%28D%29%2B+2x+cos%28C%2BD%29%3D2+-2+cos%28A%29%2C+2A%2BB%3D2+pi%2C+2D+%2B+C+%3D+2+pi%2C+0%3CB%3Cpi%2C++0%3CC%3Cpi%2C+A%2BB%2BC%2BD%2BE%3D3+pi%2C+x%3D1) sets $a=b=c=d=1$ and $e=x=1$ to solve the equilateral pentagon:
$$A\approx 2.28021, \quad B≈1.72277, \quad C\approx 1.72277, \quad D\approx 2.28021,\quad E\approx 1.41882
$$

Comment: Thank you! Can one figure out the angles from the type and the information I gave? (Are all sides really the same length? Are they the same length in your simulation?)

Comment: Hey, someone used my demo!

Comment: @EdPegg Yes indeed! And a very nice demo to boot